# Saving/Loading models in AllenNLP package

Tags: pytorch, allennlp

I am trying to load an AllenNLP model weights. I could not find any documentation on how to save/load a whole model, so playing with weights only.

```py
from allennlp.nn import util
model_state = torch.load(filename_model, map_location=util.device_mapping(-1))
model.load_state_dict(model_state)
```

I modified my input corpus a bit and I am guessing because of this I am getting corpus-size mismatch:

```py
RuntimeError: Error(s) in loading state_dict for BasicTextFieldEmbedder:

    size mismatch for token_embedder_tokens.weight: 
    copying a param with shape torch.Size([2117, 16]) from checkpoint, 
    the shape in current model is torch.Size([2129, 16]).
```

Seemingly there is no official way to save model with corpus vocabulary. Any hacks around it?

Answer (score 2):

There's a functionality in AllenNLP allowing to load or save a model.
Have you followed the steps outlined in [AllenNLP's tutorial](https://allennlp.org/tutorials)? Below I pasted a snippet from the tutorial that might be of interest to you:

```
# Here's how to save the model.
with open("/tmp/model.th", 'wb') as f:
    torch.save(model.state_dict(), f)

vocab.save_to_files("/tmp/vocabulary")

# And here's how to reload the model.
vocab2 = Vocabulary.from_files("/tmp/vocabulary")

model2 = LstmTagger(word_embeddings, lstm, vocab2)
with open("/tmp/model.th", 'rb') as f:
    model2.load_state_dict(torch.load(f))
```

If the above somehow doesn't work for you, you can check [`allennlp.models.archival.archive_model`](https://allenai.github.io/allennlp-docs/api/allennlp.models.archival.html#allennlp.models.archival.archive_model) helper function. Using this function you should be able to archive your model's training configuration along with weights and vocabulary to model.tar.gz.
[`Here`](https://github.com/allenai/allennlp/issues/2377) you can find more information on the constraints of the two approaches that I discussed